# How to scale new observations for making predictions when the model was fitted with scaled data?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, scales

I understand the concept of scaling the data matrix to use in a linear regression model. For example, in R you could use:

```
scaled.data <- scale(data, scale=TRUE)
```

My only question is, for new observations for which I want to predict the output values, how are they correctly scaled? Would it be, `scaled.new <- (new - mean(data)) / std(data)`?

Comment: To get the values back just do `y = y_esc * sd(y) + mean(y)`, but that would mess with the model properties i guess, so i'm also waiting a more technical answer too!

Comment: I don't want the values back, I want to know how new instances can be correctly scaled in the same way. I've edited my question based on your comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer to your question is, yes - that expression for scaled.new is correct (except you wanted `sd` instead of `std`).

It may be worth noting that scale has optional arguments which you could use:

```
scaled.new <- scale(new, center = mean(data), scale = sd(data))
```

Also, the object returned by scale (scaled.data) has attributes holding the numeric centering and scalings used (if any), which you could use:

```
scaled.new <- scale(new, attr(scaled.data, "scaled:center"), attr(scaled.data, "scaled:scale"))
```

The advantage of that appears when the original data has more than one column, so there are multiple means and/or standard deviations to consider.

Comment: I wish there was a slightly simpler way to do this, like `scaled.new <- scale(new, use.attrs = scaled.data)`

Comment: @wordsforthewise It wouldn't be hard to write a wrapper for scale.default to achieve that. I doubt that  R-core would give it high priority.

Comment: Yeah.  If I can figure out how to contribute to R-core and find time to do it, I might do that.

Answer (score 4):

There are now simpler ways to do this.
For example, the `preprocess` function of the `caret` package

```
library(caret)
preproc <- preProcess(data, method = c("center", "scale")
scaled.new <- predict(preproc, newdata = new)
```

or `scale_by` in the `standardize` package

or using the `receipes` package

```
library(recipes); library(dplyr)
rec <- recipe(~ ., data) %>% step_normalize(all_numeric()) %>% prep()
scaled.new <- rec %>% bake(new)
```

Comment: Upvoted. You might want to correct case in "the preprocess function of the caret package" and spelling in "using the receipes package"

Comment: Not sure if the function changed compared to nigelhenry's first comment, but it seems that "preProcess" will give you only the preprocessing values but won't change your data. Using his example, you should follow up with predict(preproc, data) and predict(preproc, new). Original example here: [Caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#centering-and-scaling)

Comment: Yes, the OP only asked about new data,  so I only provided code for that.